# Update Binding on Composite Property when Child Property Changes

Tags: wpf, vb.net, mvvm, binding, inotifypropertychanged

Let's say I have a property called `Greeting` that is principally composed of two bound properties: `LastName` and `FirstName`.  Can I subscribe to updates on first and last name so I can force a refresh with `OnPropertyChanged()` for my Greeting property.  Here's a simple example:

**View**

```xml
<TextBox Text="{Binding FirstName}" />
<TextBox Text="{Binding LastName}" />
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Greeting}" />
```

**ViewModel**

```vb
Public Property FirstName() As String
    Get
        Return _firstName
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As String)
        _firstName = value
        OnPropertyChanged("FirstName")
    End Set
End Property

'... Omitting LastName for brevity ...

Public ReadOnly Property Greeting() As String
    Get
        Return String.Format("Hello {0} {1}", Firstname, LastName)
    End Get
End Property
```

The way this is currently set up, nothing will ever update the Greeting binding.  I could put `OnPropertyChanged("Greeting")` in the setter for `FirstName` and `LastName`, but this feels wrong.  In a more complex example, I'd rather each object just take care of refreshing itself when something changes.

**Q:)** *Can I force an update for a `ReadOnly` Property when one of the Properties it's composed of changes?*

Comment: You want to do exactly what you say "feels wrong". It is right/best/prefered/normal way to go about this. Based on your "Q:)", it is really the only way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call PropertyChange of Greetings from setter of  FirstName and LastName

```vb
Public Property FirstName() As String
    Get
        Return _firstName
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As String)
        _firstName = value
        OnPropertyChanged("FirstName")
        OnPropertyChanged("Greeting")
    End Set
End Property
```

## OR

You can subscribe to `PropertyChanged` of your ViewModel in itself

```vb
AddHandler this.PropertyChanged, AddressOf PropertyChanged
```

and in `PropertyChanged` you can check which property is changed depending on that you can RaisePropertyChanged for Greeting

Comment: I already acknowledged this exact approach in my original question (`I could put OnPropertyChanged("Greeting") in the setter for FirstName and LastName`).  I was looking for something a little less tightly coupled.

Answer (score 1):

Borrowing from [nit's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19548326/update-binding-on-composite-property-when-child-property-changes#answer-19548897), just to round it out a little.  Here's what I did to fire an update on the `Greeting` property when `FirstName` or `LastName` changes:

```vb
Private Sub UpdateGreeting(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As PropertyChangedEventArgs) _
    Handles Me.PropertyChanged
    If e.PropertyName = "FirstName" OrElse e.PropertyName="LastName" Then
        OnPropertyChanged("Greeting")
    End If
End Sub
```

- It handles the `PropertyChanged` event that is already implemented as part of the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface on the ViewModel.
- Then it checks if the `PropertyName` value of the event argument is equal to "FirstName" or "LastName".
- If so, it manually raises the `OnPropertyChanged()` method for the `Greeting` property.